# Foreground service doesn't start at boot time

Tags: android, service

I am trying to start a foreground service at boot time, but it never starts, however If i try to start a normal background service. It starts perfectly fine.

Can you please let me what is wrong with my code ?

My code is:
Manifest file:

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <receiver android:name="com.test.andsrvfg.AndSrvFgService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:name="AndSrvFgService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.test.andsrvfg.AndSrvFgService"></action>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
</application>
```

BroadcastReceiver to handle ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED:

```
public class AndSrvFgStarter extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) {
            Intent i = new Intent();
            i.setAction("com.test.andsrvfg.AndSrvFgService");
            context.startService(i);
        }
    }
}
```

The actual service is like:

```
public class AndSrvFgService extends Service {

    private boolean bForeground = false;
    public AndSrvFgService() {
    }

    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        if(!bForeground) {
            bForeground = true;
            Notification note = new Notification( 0, null, System.currentTimeMillis() );
            note.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;
            startForeground( 1242, note );      
                }


        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        if(bForeground) {
            stopForeground(true);
        }
    }
```

Comment: have you given permission in AndroidManifest.xml ?

Comment: Are you sure that you manifest declared the Intent-Filter properly? You don;t have it posted, so I can't verify on my end, but that seems to be your issue.

Comment: In which version are you testing?

Comment: Yeah..i did "RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED". The same AndroidManifest.xml work well for background service. Infact if I use a activity to start foreground service, it works perfectly alright.

Comment: I have given permission  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
 in manifest file, for some reason, this entry is not appearing in question

Comment: @abbas.aniefa - version 2.1 and 4.0

Comment: check this http://commonsware.com/blog/2011/07/13/boot-completed-regression-confirmed.html

Comment: http://www.jjoe64.com/2011/06/autostart-service-on-device-boot.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code works for me:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.dfsdf"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
              android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>

        <service android:name=".MyService"/>

        <receiver android:enabled="true" 
            android:name=".BootUpReceiver"
            android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

- Put this in the receiver:

  android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"
- Set enable to true:

  android:enabled="true"

Comment: I put one comment. Now i add some extra lines. But it must works

Comment: still doesnt work.. the only difference I can see in your code and my code is - I am not using any activity. So it is just broadcast receiver and service. Please note that, the same code works fine if I start service in background instead of foreground.

Comment: See the receiver.

I put android:enabled, android:permision, and the category in te intent-filter. If you have more problems, I can upload a full working source code.

Comment: thanks moskis..I deleted project, created a new project with same settings and you know what..it is working for me..thank for your help. If you upload your code, it might help others though...

Comment: Thanks! for me was this: android:enabled="true"